# How can we set the exit button of JFileChooser?

Tags: java, swing

we use `setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE)` for `JFrame` and those classes that implements `JFrame`.

what can we do like this for `JFileChooser`?(the window that suddenly when you push browse button will pups up)

Answer (score 1):

On a closing JFileChooser you normally don't want to exit your application, at first you want to get the inputs the user made from the dialog. After that you can call System.exit() directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can put a JFileChooser on a custom JFrame and set the default close operation on that JFrame.